# Dropdown_load Event and Page_load?

Tags: c#, asp.net

1. I have to bind Drop down list when the Page load.In my previous
   Project I have used Page_Load event.Now i find an event which is
   Drop down_load event .I used Drop down_load and its Work well .
2. Is there any difference between these two events,In some cases i
   have to bind more than 10 Drop down list.
3. so which one is best?

   eg:

   ```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           if (!IsPostBack)
           { 
           //bind my Dropdown
           }
       }

       protected void ddlProduct_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            { 
               //bind my Dropdown
            }
       }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your requirement and when you want to bind your `DropDownList`s. According to ASP.Net Page Life cycle `Page_Load` event firs first and then control events, in this case the `ddlProduct_Load` event.

And, this is also true according the the `DropDownList` Load event's definition

> Fires when the page has been loaded

So, you have to make a decision where you want to bind the control.

Since you have more than 10 `DropDownLists` I would suggests to use their own load event to bind your control rather than making `Page_Load` looks too busy.